# Maxscript - accessing a variable from a function which is inside a struct

Tags: maxscript

I have nearly completed writing this struct for copying the contents of one file to a new file.

The variable `numLines` is where I'm having difficulty.

See line `46` where there's the one I'm having trouble with and the working example on line `50` along with additional comments.

I've tried using `this.numLines` as those references variables inside a struct.

And also assigning a local variable inside the fn but nothing seems to work.

```
(
  local readFilePath  = @"path to old file here.ms"
  local writeFilePath = @"path to new file here.ms"
  global _3db_FileOps
  local _3db_FileOps_Struct
  struct _3db_FileOps_Struct
  (
    readPath = readFilePath,
    writePath = writeFilePath,
    rp = dotnetobject "System.IO.Streamreader" readPath,
    wp = dotnetobject "System.IO.StreamWriter" writePath,
    currLine = 0,
    numLines = 0,
    fn CloseFiles =
    (
      try Close readPath catch() ; try Close writePath catch()
      ),
    fn CloseReaders =
    (
     try rp.Close() catch() ; try wp.Close() catch()
     ),
    fn CountLines =
    (
      while not this.rp.EndOfStream do
      (
        this.rp.ReadLine()
        numLines += 1
        if (mod numLines 500) == 0 do try windows.processPostedMessages() catch()
        )
      return numLines as integer
      close readPath
      rp.Close()
      ),
    fn CopyContents =
    (
      start = timeStamp()
      while not this.rp.EndOfStream do
      (
        arr = this.rp.ReadLine()
        this.wp.WriteLine(arr)


        --Here I want to progress the progressbar with the equation 100.*currLine/numLines which is not working.
        --The numLines variable is not working in this because if I replace that with the blocked
        --Not working because of  the variable numLines.
        --         progressTest.doit_prog.value = 100.*currLine/this.numLines


        --This works.
        progressTest.doit_prog.value = 100.*currLine/2000


        currLine += 1
        )
      rp.Close()
      wp.Close()
      end = timeStamp()
      format "Processing took % seconds\n" ((end - start) / 1000.0)
      )
    )
  _3db_FileOps = _3db_FileOps_Struct()
  )

try destroydialog progressTest catch()
rollout progressTest "Progress Test"
(
  button calculate "Scan file"
  label fileinfo "Lines in file" style_sunkenedge:true width:180 height:16
  button doit "Process file"
  progressbar doit_prog color:blue
  on calculate pressed do
  (
    start = timeStamp()
    result = _3db_FileOps.CountLines()
    _3db_FileOps.CloseFiles()
    fileinfo.text = result as string
    end = timeStamp()
    format "Processing took % milliseconds\n" ((end - start) / 1000.0)
    )
  on doit pressed do ( _3db_FileOps.CopyContents() ; _3db_FileOps.CloseFiles() )
  )
createDialog progressTest 200 120
```

Comment: What's the error message and the stack trace you're getting? The snippet as you posted it works without issues - provided that the _3db_FileOps.CloseFiles() line is uncommented, as the CloseFiles is not included in your post. If I assume it closes both streams, then calling that before CopyContents results in a 'Cannot read from a closed TextReader' excepion.

Comment: I was trying to keep the code down in the OP. I've amended the code now with the two fns for closing the reader and files. But this isn't affecting the line '46' where `this.numLines` doesn't seem to be evaluating correctly to progress the progressbar.